How does sleep work?
In pathfinder 2e remastered, we had a situation where we had a single giant wasp that was our opponent. I cast sleep on it, and it fell asleep. Then the debating started, and hasn't full stopped. We were debating the single strike death blow that can happen with D&D, but the rules don't seem to be the same in pathfinder. What I think should have happened is this.

If no combat was happening, everyone could move to be in position, doing so under sneak rules, with a -4 perception check against the stealth DC of each player. Then a single player can do a single strike where they do a stealth check, if they pass just auto assume a critical strike with max dice. Probably not quite rules, but...
If there is someone who isn't trying to be sneaky there is a DC set on the sleepy enemy depending on what they are doing. A sword strike nearby is louder than a bow strike from far away.

Does this seem reasonable?

The existing answer is fairly comprehensive, but I want to also note that, given your party was fighting a Giant Wasp as a single boss encounter, it was probably higher level than you. That means that the Incapacitation trait is in play. In short - if the Wasp merely “failed” its saving throw, it should not have been put to sleep at all. Assuming a level 2 Wizard casting Sleep, with +4 Int, (DC 16), means that the Wasp would only fall asleep on a natural 1 (1+6 for a 7 will save, downgraded by one degree of success for Nat 1).

It wasn't a boss encounter, just a random encounter in the woods. But I'll have to look more at the incapacitation trait, so much to learn...

By “boss” I simply meant “encounter with a single enemy of higher level than the party.”

"Coup de grâce"
Pathfinder 2e did not inherit any form of this technique, so your GM is completely in home-brew territory for any benefits allotted against unconscious targets.
Depending on the GM's prerogative, and the danger imposed by a single 'Creature 3', it could be argued that you are no longer in a combat situation and could resolve things without keeping or even using initiative. Again, there are no guidelines, I'm just providing one route they could choose.
Using the dice as intended
Unconscious, notably of the kind caused by the sleep spell (until upcast to 4th Rank by a level 7 or higher spellcaster):

This spell doesn't prevent creatures from waking up due to a successful Perception check, limiting its utility in combat.
At the start of your turn, you automatically attempt a Perception check against the noise's DC (or the lowest DC if there is more than one noise), waking up if you succeed. If creatures are attempting to stay quiet around you, this Perception check uses their Stealth DCs.

You can act freely (barring the other causes for ending the Condition) until the Wasp's turn, at which point it uses it's Perception (-4) against the noise DC set by the DM. The exact DC isn't given by the book (unless the entire party is Avoiding Notice/Hiding and Sneaking, see below) and should probably be chosen from the list of Simple DC's, Untrained being the most likely at DC 10, altered by an appropriate Difficulty Adjustment.
If the party is being stealthy, then the Perception DC is your lowest Stealth DC. A reasonable GM would probably disregard anyone not trying to do anything if they are standing completely still (such as anyone Untrained and trying not to mess it up for the rest of you), but there is nothing saying that is the 'correct' way to handle it.
Assuming you are able to reach the subject without waking them, you would be able to Strike their AC -6 (-2 circumstance for Off-guard and -4 status more for unconscious) which should, all other things being even, give them an excellent chance of gaining a natural Critical hit. However, the first person to successfully Strike the character will wake them up, dealing their typical damage or double critical as normal.

I missed it is at the start of their turn. That might make things a bit more interesting...

of note, a high perception seems to make sleeping impossible. being a high level adventurer with lower level roommates is just forever fatigued

Haha there's a funny image. Although "Loud noise around you might wake you" and including a separate line for "If you are simply asleep" leaves the implications clear.

@Ifusaso's answer is correct as per the rules. His suggestion of running with the dice as explicitly written in the rules is a valid approach. I'm sharing this to mention what I have done (in the very few situations something similar has come up):
Step 1: Does the Wasp Awaken?
You mention in a comment that it's the start of the wasp's turn. It should get the normal roll allowed by Sleep to see if it awakens (as @Ifusaso describes). Additionally, @LessPop_MoreFizz's comment on the Incapacitation trait should be followed up on.
Assuming the wasp doesn't wake up, proceed to step 2:
Step 2: The Wasp is dead
I've ran coup de grace's (killing helpless enemies) as instant death. As the suggestions in Ending the Encounter from the GM Core remind us:

You can decide a fight is over if there's no challenge left ... you can simply say the battle is over and that the PCs easily dispatch their remaining foes. In [this] case, you might ask, “Is everyone okay if we call the fight?” to make sure your players are on board.

It's worked out fine for me. Realistically, a level+1 enemy that is the only enemy in a fight that lets someone get a hit on them while they're unconscious is going to die anyway without doing much more meaningful damage. This makes more narrative sense (a lot more, especially with normal foes like humanoids and animals). Hit points are NOT health points, but rather:

Your maximum Hit Point value represents your health, wherewithal, and heroic drive when you're in good health and rested.

So I run it as "this enemy just dies" successfully. Since it's really rare to actually significantly incapacitate a significant enemy (due to that pesky Incapacitation trait), this rarely comes up when it would be game breaking.
NB: I've only done this when there is no other combat going on. In the midst of combat, I've just said "it's hard to find the time to properly line up a kill shot while maintaining your defenses" and had them go by the RAW path (as Ifusaso describes).
